# Nifi error HiveStreaming$ShouldRetryException in puthivestreaming

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying with nifi 1.4. I am using ConsumeKafkaRecord_0_10 and PutHiveStreaming processor. I am getting pipe delimited messages which is parsed with CSVReader and wriiten by using AvroRecordSetWriter. But now I am getting below error.

```
2017-11-06 11:11:02,699 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6]o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=819a7fe2-015f-1000-7097-cd3f8614c9c2] Error connecting to Hive endpoint: table oneviewtest3 at thrift://parent.rolta.com:9083
2017-11-06 11:11:02,699 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=819a7fe2-015f-1000-7097-cd3f8614c9c2] Hive Streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to retry. org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://parent.rolta.com:9083', database='default', table='oneviewtest3', partitionVals=[] }:
org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$ShouldRetryException: Hive Streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to retry. org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://parent.rolta.com:9083', database='default', table='oneviewtest3', partitionVals=[] }
org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$ShouldRetryException: Hive Streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to retry. org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://parent.rolta.com:9083', database='default', table='oneviewtest3', partitionVals=[] }
```

Below is my table schema,

```
create table oneviewtest3  (TNT_KEY BIGINT, PLANT_KEY BIGINT, UNIT_KEY  BIGINT, TAG_DATA_SRC STRING, TAG_DATA_RLVNC STRING, TAG_TYPE_ID STRING, DB_RQST_ID STRING, BATCH_KEY BIGINT, OPC_TAG_ID  STRING, OPC_TAG_VAL_TS STRING, OPC_SRC_STM_CODE BIGINT, OPC_TAG_VAL STRING, OPC_QLTY_VAL BIGINT, REF_ID STRING, REF_TYPE STRING, ERROR_CODE STRING, OPC_TAG_VAL_AGG_TYPE STRING, OPC_TAG_RSMPL_INTRVL_VAL BIGINT, OPC_TAG_RSMPL_INTRVL_TYPE STRING, OPC_TAG_VAL_TS_PRC  STRING, FLEX_FIELD1 STRING, FLEX_FIELD2 STRING, FLEX_FIELD3 STRING, FLEX_FIELD4 STRING, FLEX_FIELD5 STRING, ETL_BTCH_ID  BIGINT) CLUSTERED BY (OPC_TAG_ID) into 4 buckets stored as orc tblproperties ("transactional"="true","orc.compress"="NONE");
```

So I am already following below in table create statement,

1.ORC format for table. So table has "stored as orc"

2.transactional = "true" is set in the table create statement

3.Bucketed but not sorted. So table has "clustered by (colName) into (n) buckets"

And also done following,

1. hive.support.concurrency = true
2. hive.enforce.bucketing = true
3. hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
4. hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
5. hive.compactor.initiator.on = true
6. hive.compactor.worker.threads = 2

So can anybody please help me on it.

Comment: I am using HDP 2.5.3 and I also see in nifi lib folder nifi-hive-nar-1.4.0.nar

Comment: And in hivemetastore getting error as,                                                                 2017-11-06 12:02:53,436 ERROR [pool-8-thread-192]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(297)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected DataOperationType: UNSET agentInfo=Unknown txnid:424

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?.

Comment: No. It seems HDP 2.5.3 and NiFi 1.4 not compatible. I am using HDF now.